# error: NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, adapter

I'm trying to set an Adapter this way to display a ListView:

```
public class DrugAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    Resources resources;

    private List<DrugModel> drug;
    private LayoutInflater myInflater;

    public DrugAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DrugModel> listOfDrugs) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, listOfDrugs);

        this.context = context;
        this.drug = listOfDrugs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        resources = context.getResources();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_description);

        name.setText(drug.get(position).getName()); // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR MESSAGE OCCURS
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
        name.setTypeface(tf);
        description.setText(drug.get(position).getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.mypharmacy.adapters.DrugAdapter.getView(DrugAdapter.java:47)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
>             at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
>             at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
> ```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mypharmacy.app.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_drugs_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_for_a_drug"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_drugs"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_drugs_edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="425dp"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="70dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name: init value"
        android:textColor="#008019"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description: init value"
        android:textColor="#0080A9"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With which I couldn't be able to figure out what's wrong. How to fix this, please ? Why does the `name` variable takes the value of Null ?

Comment: check the value in drug.get(position).getName() i think it is null

Comment: If `name` is null, it means that no view with id `list_item_name` was found in the layout `activity_main`. Can you show us the layout?

Comment: you need to debug to determine whether `name` is null or `drug.get(position)` is null

Comment: @Gaëtan, Android studio doesn't tell me that `list_item_name` wasn't found.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, `drug.get(position)` isn't null when I log `drug.get(position).toString()` I get the correct string result.

Comment: @user3797031 post `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Are you sure that you should be inflating `R.layout.activity_main` instead of something else that's actually storing the view for the given list item?

Comment: @Raghunandan, I've just updated my post, posting `activity_main.xml` and `list_item.xml`.

Comment: @user3797031 change to `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);`

Comment: @Raghunandan, doing that I get `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made` on `name.setTypeface(tf);`

Comment: @user3797031 comment that line and check. it has nothing to do with the update. You are setting a font. check that you do that properly and arial.ttf exists in assests folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is in this line.

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

You are probably inflating the wrong layout, if that is the case, even if you call this line:

```
convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
```

and `R.id.list_item_name` is valid, that id is not in that layout. If you call to `findViewById` having inflated a different layout, you will receive a null item.

Hope it helps

Comment: I've just updated my post, posting `activity_main.xml` and `list_item.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity_main.xml` does not have a `TextView` with id `list_item_name`. The `TextView` name is null.

Change this

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

to

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

Also consider using a `ViewHolder` pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html